# Why is the type undefined in my output?

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop, undefined

I'm getting undefined under the TYPE column after I run my code. I looked my functions and they seem fine to me. The TYPE column should be either Child, Junior, or Adult. You can put 10 for the prompts saying how many tickets sold and what is the charge.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">     
    var BR = "<br />";
    var JUNIOR_PRICE = 7.50;
    var ADULT_PRICE = 11.50;

        function main()
        {
            var ticketType;
            var quantity = 0;
            var charge = 0.00;
            var ticketName;
            var currentDate = "";
            var cAccum = 0;
            var jAccum = 0;
            var aAccum = 0;
            var numTickets = 0;
            var countNumber = 0;
            var delta = 0.00;
            var totRevenueC = 0.00;
            var totRevenueJ = 0.00;
            var totRevenueA = 0.00;
            var totRevenue = 0.00;
            var ticketsSold = 0.00;

            document.write("SUMMERVILLE SEAWORLD" + BR);
            currentDate = prompt("What is today's date? (ex: October 11, 2014)", "");
            document.write("Summary report for " + currentDate + BR);

            ticketType = getTicketType();

            while (ticketType != 'Q')
            {
                quantity = getQuantity();
                charge = getCharge();

                if (ticketType == "C")
                {
                    cAccum += quantity;
                    delta = 0;
                    totRevenueC = 0;
                }
                else if (ticketType == "J")
                {
                    jAccum += quantity;
                    delta = charge - (quantity * JUNIOR_PRICE);
                    totRevenueJ = (jAccum * JUNIOR_PRICE) - delta;
                }
                else
                {
                    aAccum += quantity;
                    delta = charge - (quantity * ADULT_PRICE);
                    totRevenueA = (aAccum * ADULT_PRICE) - delta;
                }

                countNumber ++;
                ticketsSold += quantity;
                totRevenue = totRevenueC + totRevenueJ + totRevenueA;

                ticketType = getTicketType();

                displayOneOrder(countNumber, ticketName, quantity, charge, delta);
            }
            displayFinalReport(currentDate, countNumber, aAccum, totRevenueA, jAccum, totRevenueJ, cAccum, totRevenueC, totRevenue);
        }

        function getTicketType()
        {
            var tickType;

            tickType = prompt("Enter ticket type: C, J, A or Q to quit", "");
            tickType = tickType.toUpperCase();
            while (tickType != "C" && tickType != "J" && tickType != "A" && tickType != "Q")
            {
                tickType = prompt("Invalid entry.  Enter ticket: C, J, A or Q to quit", "");
                tickType = tickType.toUpperCase();
            }
            return tickType;
        }

        function getQuantity()
        {
            var qty;
            qty = prompt("How many tickets sold?", "");
            qty = parseFloat(qty);
            //Validation loop for a negative amount
            while (qty < 0.0)
            {
                qty = prompt ("Negative sale values are not allowed! Please enter the sale for that region:", "");
                qty = parseInt(qty);
            }
            return qty;
        }

        function getCharge()
        {
            var chrg;
            chrg = prompt("What is the charge?", "");
            chrg = parseFloat(chrg);
            //Validation loop for a negative amount
            while (chrg < 0.0)
            {
                chrg = prompt ("Negative sale values are not allowed! Please enter the sale for that region:", "");
                chrg = parseFloat(chrg);
            }
            return chrg;                
        }

        function findTicketName(tickType)
        {
            var tickName;

            if (tickType == "C")
            {
                tickName = "Child";
            }
            else if (tickType == "J")
            {
                tickName = "Junior";
            }
            else
            {
                tickName = "Adult";
            }
            return tickName;            
        }

        function displayOneOrder(count, tickName, qty, chrg, delt)
        {
            document.writeln("<pre>");
            document.writeln("COUNTER #" + "    " + "TYPE" + "      " + "QTY" + "       " + "ACTUAL CHG" + "    " + "DELTA");
            document.writeln(count + "      " + tickName + "        " + qty + "     " + chrg.toFixed(2) + "     " + delt.toFixed(2) + BR);
            document.writeln("</pre>");
        }

        function displayFinalReport(currDate, count, aduAccum, totRevA, junAccum, totRevJ, chiAccum, totRevC, totRev)
        {
            document.write("SUMMERVILLE SEAWORLD" + BR + BR);
            document.write("Summary report for " + currDate + BR + BR);
            document.write("Number of records: " + count + BR + BR);
            document.write("SALES TOTALS");

            document.writeln("<pre>");
            document.writeln("TICKET TYPE" + "  " + "TOTAL TICKETS" + "     " + "TOTAL REVENUE");
            document.writeln("ADULT" + "             " + aduAccum + "              " + totRevA.toFixed(2) + BR);
            document.writeln("JUNIOR" + "            " + junAccum + "              " + totRevJ.toFixed(2) + BR);
            document.writeln("CHILD" + "             " + chiAccum + "              " + totRevC.toFixed(2) + BR + BR);
            document.writeln("TOTAL REVENUE: " + totRev.toFixed(2));
            document.writeln("</pre>");
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Because you're passing the function that prints it the `ticketName`  variable, which never has a value assigned to it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do in the function findTicketName. It receives tickType from the function getTicketType. Then I want the tickName to display it in the function displayOneOrder.

Comment: findTicketName is never called anywhere in your code, this is why it is unassigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is change this line:

```
displayOneOrder(countNumber, ticketName, quantity, charge, delta);
```

...to this:

```
displayOneOrder(countNumber, ticketType, quantity, charge, delta);
```

In other words, you passed `ticketName` for that second parameter when you meant to pass `ticketType` instead.

UPDATE: Or, if you want it to show the full name of the ticket type (e.g., "Adult" instead of "A"), then either change that line to this:

```
displayOneOrder(countNumber, findTicketName(ticketType), quantity, charge, delta);
```

...or precede it with a line to set the value of `ticketName`, like so:

```
ticketName = findTicketName(ticketType);
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing ticketName = findTicketName(ticketType)